# MVC.net Dynamic bootstrap Modal content call another cshtml file but the javascript in the partial view is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have page with table list of employee, when the user click one of the list, its trigger a function to create a modal and call a partial view from controller based on the item clicked and send the parameter,
im using @url.Action to send the parameter to the javascript to generate the modal and it shows correctly,
however all the javascript inside the partial view is not working.
How to enable all the script within the partialview cshtml file (ViewPMEmployee)?

Html

```
<tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Employee)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center cb-width">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="@item.EmployeeCd" onclick="return EmployeeProperties('@item.EmployeeCd')" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="form-control-static td1">
                            @*<a href="/PMEmployee/ViewPMEmployee?employeeCd=@item.EmployeeCd">@item.EmployeeCd.ToString()</a>*@
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-link" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("ViewPMEmployee", "PMEmployee", new { employeeCd = item.EmployeeCd })" data-backdrop="false">@item.EmployeeCd.ToString()</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            <font class="form-control-static">@item.EmployeeNm</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {

    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myModal").remove();
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();

        $.get($(this).data("targeturl"), function (data) {
            $('<div id="myModal" class="modal right fade" role="dialog" style="left:350px">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body">' +
                data + '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button ></div ></div></div ></div>').modal();
            $(".modal-backdrop").addClass("d-none");
                            });
                        });
});
```

Comment: Seeing the partial view is relevant. Is your script in an @section of the partial? That won't work.

Comment: @SteveGreene there is no "@section" in the partialview , its only contain html and some javascript function in "<script></script>" tag.
I didn't post the partial view because its too long

Comment: Events are wiped out when you replace the DOM, so set your events after you have updated the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place the partial view javascript code above the HTML section within the partial view. Or you can move the Code in a separate javascript file and include the script in partial view above the partial view HTML. hopefully, it works.

Comment: I have tried to placed the partialview's javascript into the parent view outsde the section, but still not working, I need to use "onClick" to each list to trigger the js function. but some of the script can't implementng onClick to run.